# Trim string by strings

Tags: c#

How can I trim a string by a whole string instead of a list of single characters?

I want to remove all `&nbsp;` and whitespaces at beginning and end of an HTML string. But method `String.Trim()` does only have overloads for set of characters and not for set of strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(String)` and use the resultant as an input for `String.Trim()`

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)
[HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) (a wrapper you can access through the [Page.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.page.server.aspx) property)

```
string stringWithNonBreakingSpaces;
string trimmedString =  String.Trim(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(stringWithNonBreakingSpaces));
```

**Note:** This solution would decode all the HTML strings in the input.

Comment: I would also have done that :-) If @brgerner does not want to decode and re-encode the string, a Regex would also do the trick.

Comment: Yes, true I agree I would have gone the regex route too or even a `String.Replace`. Made me add the side note :)

Comment: @ABKolan Thanks, that works (with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(String)`) for `&nbsp;`. Is there also a method to trim `\n` and `\r`?

Answer (score 2):

The Trim method removes from the current string all leading and trailing white-space characters by default.

Edit: Solution for your problem AFTER your edit:

```
string input = @"  &nbsp; <a href='#'>link</a>  &nbsp; ";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(&nbsp;|\s)*|(&nbsp;|\s)*$");
string result = regex.Replace(input, String.Empty);
```

This will remove all trailing and leading spaces and `&nbsp;`. You can add any string or character group to the expression. If you were to trim all tabs too the regex would simply become:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(&nbsp;|\s|\t)*|(&nbsp;|\s|\t)*$");
```

Comment: @brgerner wants to remove the text `"&nbsp;"` from the string

Comment: I edited my question: my first version swallowed the text: `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Till +1 If he needs `&nbsp;` in the middle, thats the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for?

```
   string str = "hello &nbsp;";
   str.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
   str.Trim();
```

Comment: This will replace everywhere, not at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Use RegEx, as **David Heffernan** said. It is rather easy to select all spaces at the start of string:    `^(\ |&nbsp;)*`

Comment: He wants to trim string both at the start and at the end

Comment: This is just a hint, not complete solution